# how to check the children length of a div in html angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i have a scenario to display a  if another div exist. How to check this in angular js html page...

In my .js file i can search for element.find().length . Butcan i check the same in html page itself

here is what i have to try .

The scenario is if there is a page exist i dont want to show one error message div . 
This is my index page

```
<div class="body-content">
    <div  class="p-row" ></div> 
    <div data-ng-if="**here to check if there is a content already in the body**" class="error-message-panel"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: use init on that div and do the same js things and return that to html

Comment: pure HTML to check if element length is > 0 does not exists. You will have to use JS code; even if you add it into the ng-if directly OR call a function

Comment: It would almost certainly be better to base this ng-if on the same data model that controls whether that other div exists, instead of searching the DOM for it the other div

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<div class="body-content">
        <div  class="p-row" ></div> 
        <div data-ng-if="$('div').length" class="error-message-panel"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Here replace $('div') with the length of perticular div or class